# in tensorflow 1.15 / Keras, how to pass the value of a variable into the loss at every batch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Tensorflow 1.15 with Keras.

I have this code, called at every batch:

```
some_var = some_value

net.train_on_batch(train_subdata_batch_cache, train_subdata_to_batch_cache)
```

Where *some_var* changes its value at every batch. I want to use *some_var* for one of the term of the loss function, and I want this term to be updated accordingly at every batch.

Any idea on how to do this ?

Thanks